# use a central linux machine for ssh authentication

Tags: linux, ssh, remote

I have multiple Linux machines that I want to use the credentials from a central, network reachable, machine to avoid the hustle of distributing passswords from the central machine to each machine.

Is there a way to easily achieve this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ldap

Comment: @IporSircer from "LDAP" to "have a working Linux domain with centralized login": there's a few steps missing ;)

Comment: Here you are: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LDAP_authentication

Comment: You could add a PAM-entry ([pam_listfile](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_listfile)) and  point to a file on a (read-only) mounted directory from the centralized server using keypairs and locked-down access. Not tested and just a concept, so no real answer.

Comment: @FelixJN you'd be rediscovering half of Sun's NIS (Yellow Pages) :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are LOTS of ways of achieving this. The most common solution is LDAP. IMHO its not the easiest, but its still the mechansim I would recommend.

You didn't say what Linux distribution(s) you were using which might have given some clues about the best approach. There are 2 LDAP servers commonly used on linux; 389Directory and openLDAP. But life is a lot simpler of you also have a tools for configuring the service and managing the data beyond the command line tools which come bundled with these. For OpenLDAP, that means using 3rd party tools such as https://www.ldap-account-manager.org/lamcms/ . I suggest you have a look at FreeIPA (uses 389directory at the backend).

(A few years ago I wuold also have mentioned GoSA - but that project seems a lot less acive now - https://www.gonicus.de/aktuelles/20220202-gosa_update2_8/).

Answer (score 1):

Samba as a server to provide an implementation of, and usable interface into, Active Directory ("AD"). If you already have Microsoft AD available on-site and can use it as your credential source then you don't even need this step. (Note that Azure Active Directory is a different solution entirely and cannot be used in this scenario.)

Either Samba (with `winbind`) or `sssd` on the clients to handle authentication from AD.